# Unable to Install JavaFX on Eclipse on MacOS

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I am unable to install JavaFX on Eclipse. I get this error message when attempting to run HelloFX:

> Error: Could not find or load main class javafx.fxml   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javafx.fxml

I have a Mac Pro 5,1 running MacOS 10.14.6 Mojave. It is heavily upgraded, and I do not believe that this is the issue, although it is a 2012 machine.

I have tried earlier and later versions of JDK, JFX and Eclipse. Either with no change or worse results. AdoptOpenJDK version 8.0 produced additional errors. Currently I have installed:

AdoptOpenJDK 16 and AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 were both tried, and placed in the usual directory:
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/

This line was added to .bash_profile
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-16.jdk/Contents/Home

javafx-sdk-11.0.2 was placed in:
/Library/Java/Extensions/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
And the following line added to .bash_profile:
export PATH_TO_FX=Library/Java/Extensions/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib

Eclipse Version: 2021-03 (4.19.0) was installed using the installer app. version 1.20.0, after clearing out the 'hidden' config files from earlier versions.

/Users/baron/JWS was configured as the Java Work Space. All old java project, packets and other files were removed to a backup location before installation of Eclipse.
A project was built using the HelloFX files from openjfx "Getting Started with JavaFX".

~/JWS/HelloJFX/src/HelloFX/Controller.java

~/JWS/HelloJFX/src/HelloFX/Hellofx.fxml

~/JWS/HelloJFX/src/HelloFX/Main.java

A user library was created from the jar files:
Preferences/Java/Build Path/User Libraries/JavaFX11

The User Library contained all the expected components. The User Library JavaFX11 was attached to the project, and appeared as expected.

Main args were added as follows:
--module-path /path/to/javafx-sdk-15.0.1/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

This was copy pasted from the openjfx.io site, so there is no typing error here. Indeed, I followed exactly the instruction on this site.

Incidentally, it was not possible to run any java from the command line if it contained javafx imports (but that is a separate problem).

I have lost days on this already. The answers to others with the similar difficulties have not helped in my case. Expert help very welcome.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/?

Comment: Also: there's something very strange in your setup if it thinks the main class is `javafx.fxml`.

Comment: As you can see on the video, I followed the instructions. I then confirmed that I had followed them correctly by watching the video by Prof. San, here: 
https://youtu.be/vYcyu8GVtRk 
I then followed the video closely (again the same steps) with the same result. 

Setting up from the command line also failed with the error message: 
error: module not found: javafx.controls 

The path had been set correctly in bash_profile.

Comment: Your video is completely unreadable; the text is impossible to read. What are your run configurations (include them in the question). There is clearly something in the way you're trying to run it (just read the error message).\

Comment: Thank you for trying to view my video. It was made on a 4K screen. If yours is smaller, the text will be too small. If you watch prof.San you will see exactly what I did (link above) Run configuration included a VM arguments line: 

--module-path "/Library/Java/Extensions/javafx-sdk-16/lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml

Comment: You may want to read [ask]. Most people  won't bother watching a video. Also, links can break, especially for files on dropbox, and that will make your question useless for others with similar problems. Make sure your question stands on its own.

Answer (score 1):

## JDK with JavaFX bundled

One option is to install a Java implementation on your Mac that comes bundled with the [*OpenJFX*](https://openjfx.io/) ([*JavaFX*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaFX)) libraries.

At least two vendors provide such a [JDK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit):

- [*ZuluFX*](https://www.azul.com/products/zulu-enterprise/zulufx-faq/) by Azul Systems
- [*LibericaFX*](https://bell-sw.com/pages/supported-configurations/) by BellSoft

Comment: Are there any known issues with these on MacOS?

Comment: @BaronBar Not sure what you mean. These products are based on the OpenJDK project. So the code base is thoroughly reviewed and tested, for every release of Java. Apple is a key participant in OpenJDK having contributed and maintained most of the Mac-specific code. I’m sure you’ll find some bugs and issues as with any software — check the issue tracker for anything of concern to you. I would choose the latest version, currently Java 16, if there is no reason limiting you to earlier versions.

Comment: @BaronBar [Java for Apple Silicon](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/8264131) is done, but not released officially. Currently available in early-access Java 17. Testing now would be helpful if you are targeting that hardware.

Comment: Java ZuluFX has solved all the problems: Both command line and Eclipse are working as expected with FX imports. It was necessary to hunt through the directories and delete old config files before getting this to work. Eclipse leaves a forest of these in the working directory, and neglecting to remove these earlier may have been the source of the problem. And to be sure I also removed some old Oracle configs from the /Library/Application Support/Java folder (which may have been causing difficulties).